# Need regular expression to extract url path and query parameters from any url

Tags: regex, url

consider below is the input url:

```
"http://www.shopme.com/men/shirts.php?name=santosh&surname=kore";
```

I need a regular expression which will output me query path strings like `men`, `shirts` and query parameters values like `santosh`, `kore`.

I am very new to regex, please help.

Comment: Have you considered learning about it then attempting it? If not, just try building it here: http://txt2re.com/

Comment: What language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var uri = 'http://your.domain/product.aspx?category=4&product_id=2140&query=lcd+tv';
var queryString = {};
uri.replace(
    new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
    function($0, $1, $2, $3) { queryString[$1] = $3; }
);
console.log('ID: ' + queryString['product_id']);     // ID: 2140
console.log('Name: ' + queryString['product_name']); // Name: undefined
console.log('Category: ' + queryString['category']); // Category: 4
```

Originally from [here](http://stevenbenner.com/2010/03/javascript-regex-trick-parse-a-query-string-into-an-object/)